# Show modal pop up with animation Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, css-transitions

I'm trying to make an appearance animation with Vue. making the modal pop up element appear from `opacity: 0`, to `opacity: 1`, changing dynamically the styles, depending on the state value. What am I missing? It should transition on clicking the image.

```html
<img @click="show" />
<div
  v-if="showModal"
  class="modal"
  :style="[showModal ? { opacity: 1 } : { opacity: 0 }]"
></div>
```

```js
function show() {
  this.showModal = true;
}
```

```css
.modal {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

I'm expecting  to show the modal pop up block slowly with an animation of 2 seconds

Comment: Have you tried using https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#the-transition-component?

Comment: The transition doesn't run because it's tied to the element also entering/leaving the DOM at the same time.  Follow Goga's suggestion and use Vue's built-in `<Transition>` component to help with that.  I'm also concerned `this.showModal` isn't correct usage. If you're using Composition API you shouldn't use `this`, and if you're using Options API the function should be inside `methods` and shouldn't have `function` keyword

Answer (score 0):

Try that codes:

1. Define the transition component in your Vue component's template section:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Modal trigger button -->
    <button @click="openModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal with transition -->
    <transition name="modal-fade">
      <div v-if="isModalOpen" class="modal">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <!-- Modal close button -->
          <button @click="closeModal">Close Modal</button>
          <!-- Add your modal content here -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

2. Define the CSS animation for the transition in your component's style section:

```
<style>
  .modal-fade-enter-active,
  .modal-fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
  }

  .modal-fade-enter,
  .modal-fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .modal-content {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
  }
</style>
```

That's it it should be work. :)